# How to exclude verbose_name_plural field from migration?

Tags: django, django-models

Good afternoon! I'm using the verbose_name_plural dynamic field to show some up-to-date information in the admin panel.
Django version: 4.1
The model looks like this:

```py
from django.utils.functional import lazy
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Post(models.Model):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = lazy(lambda: _('Posts ({})').format(Post.....count()), str)()
```

I don't remember where I found this option to display some information, but it works great, except that every time the value changes and the command to create migrations is run, I get something like this:

```py
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='post',
            options={'verbose_name': 'Post', 'verbose_name_plural': 'Posts (123)'},
        ),
    ]
```

I found this option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39801321/2166371
But I don’t know how relevant it is and why a class that is not used is imported there

Comment: Editing the admin page would be better that changing how migrations are run imo - see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241906/display-number-of-instances-for-each-model-in-djangos-admin-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the variant that [0sVoid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13448841/0svoid) suggested, I implemented a slightly different one that seems to work without problems.

Initially, it was proposed to change one method in the main class of the admin panel (`_build_app_dict`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71740645/2166371

But there is too much code in this method that I didn't want to rewrite

I rewrote another method `get_app_list`

Parent method:

```py
    def get_app_list(self, request, app_label=None):
        """
        Return a sorted list of all the installed apps that have been
        registered in this site.
        """
        app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request, app_label)

        # Sort the apps alphabetically.
        app_list = sorted(app_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x["name"].lower())

        # Sort the models alphabetically within each app.
        for app in app_list:
            app["models"].sort(key=lambda x: x["name"])

        return app_list
```

My version:

```py
    def get_app_list(self, request, app_label=None):
        """
        Return a sorted list of all the installed apps that have been
        registered in this site.
        """
        app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request, app_label)

        # Sort the apps alphabetically.
        app_list = sorted(app_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x["name"].lower())

        # Sort the models alphabetically within each app.
        for app in app_list:
            app["models"].sort(key=lambda x: x["name"])

            for model in app['models']:
                if hasattr(model['model'], 'get_name_admin_panel'):
                    model['name'] = model['model'].get_name_admin_panel()

        return app_list
```

I have added 3 new lines, before return (these lines can also be added before sorting if sequence is important to you)

There is a check that if the `get_name_admin_panel` method is described for the model, then we change its name to the one that the method returns

In the model itself, I added the following lines:

```py
    @classmethod
    def get_name_admin_panel(cls):
        return _('Posts ({})').format(Post.objects.filter(...).count())
```

Thanks to this, I can now set a static value for the `verbose_name_plural` field and the migration will not be repeated many times

If you do not specify a `@classmethod`, then unfortunately the admin panel page will load with an error, but I didn't see any problem with that.